# Is it necessary to include the login for every usecase?

Tags: uml, use-case

I am going to design a system that has a login facility. After login the logged user can do several things so is it needed to include `login` usecase by that several usecases?

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, it will only clutter up your diagrams. Login is neither complex (*) nor does it give you much added value as a use case. In your textual document that includes the use cases with description, include as a prerequisite a list of features that require a successful login. Easier to track and to test.

(*) In regards to the *expected outcome* from the *user's perspective*. Login could be of an arbitrary *technical* complexity but that is irrelevant for the use case diagram.

Comment: Rather, Login is a constraint that can be attached to a use case.