# UML use case diagram for recruitment system

Tags: uml

[Here](http://postimg.org/image/g6drrifa9/) is my attempt on creating the use case diagram for a recruitment system.

Login use case is a pre-requisite of most of the other use cases. I am just wondering if I am right to do it like this or should I just have the Login use case for the Generic user and admin?

Since it's a pre-requisite, my initial thought was that they should have a includes relationship. However, I did some research and I am not sure if it is required to show the dependencies between the use cases on my use case diagram?

Or is it necessary to have the Login use case in the diagram at all?

Any advice?

UML Diagram here: http://postimg.org/image/g6drrifa9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very good that you spotted by yourself that this is an issue.
In fact, leave out the login. It is not a use case but a prerequisite.

See here: [Is it necessary to include the login for every usecase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443682/is-it-necessary-to-include-the-login-for-every-usecase)