# Are the roles and functions on UML use case diagram aligned correctly?

Tags: uml, use-case

I have created a use case diagram for site similar to oDesk.

**Site description:** the place, where freelancers can find suitable jobs accordingly to their skills and pricing demands and where employers/clients can find suitable freelancers for their job postings with necessary skills and for stated price.

**The goal of the site owner is**: get income, by means of taking 10% fee from every payment made from employer/client to freelancer.

Have a look at the link below. Will be happy to hear any comments and advices!

[image]

Comment: This is more a question of design review, not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Don't agree, this diagram includes possible general functions the future site should have. So, if anyone has experience in defining roles and aligning in a right way use cases for each actor - would like to hear advices.

Comment: Magnilex is right. "Does it make any sense" is not a good question that can be answered in the SO format. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for comment, changed the the format.

Comment: Undone the vote-down.

Comment: As a hint: Login is too small for being a use-case. Make it a prerequisite. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443682/is-it-necessary-to-include-the-login-for-every-usecase; "communicate" is very diffuse and potentially never-ending. Rephrase that to something more encapsulated and well-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From use full functionality point of view (it is what UseCase defines) your diagram is almost perfect. BUT, remove login usecase (it is not service..no body use system to login. Login is precondition for accessing security website functionality). Separate profile manage, block profile and other administration services (usecase) from the rest and build new diagram for them. There are mix of incompatible use cases at the same place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new here, but this question looks suitable for Business Analysts. This diagram does make sense. From my point of view, i would have added a "user" role (generalization of "employer" and "freelancer)". And aligned functions similar to "freelancer" and "employer" with "user" role.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Make Payment" use case is off.  You have it so that only the Employer doesn't make payments to anyone except possibly himself.  Consider making the two types of payment into specializations of Make Payment (remove all the extends and includes except from the Make Payment to the Process Transaction), associating the Employer with the main use case, and associating the Site Owner and Freelancer each with the appropriate specialized use case.

Also, as Vladimir says, you might consider splitting this up into multiple diagrams.