# How to create notification system Use Case diagram

Tags: use-case

I want create Use Case diagram for a notification system

In this system I have two actors `admin` and `user` ,

`admin` must first login in to the system then can add new notification and can edit it.

`user` must first select the type of notification that it wants to receive, and then can show the notification.

These are my actors and use cases:

[image: Use Case diagram]

But I don't know about the relationship between them,
How to do it?

It's true?

[image: exm]

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to get rid of the "login" use case. Here is why: [Is it necessary to include the login for every usecase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443682/is-it-necessary-to-include-the-login-for-every-usecase/19445361#19445361)

Second step: Think about the outcomes that bring a benefit.

In this scenario, I believe "select type" brings not much benefit. That can go into your usecase description.

Does "show notification" bring an added value?

"New notification" does not include a verb. It should be "create notification".

Once you get rid of intermediate steps and only show what really adds a value for the user, you won't have such a large amount of relationships.

Often "include" and "extend" only show that the use cases are specified in a  too detailed way.