# Use Case Modelling

Tags: use-case

I have 2 questions regarding use cases,

**1.** If I signed in to a website and did no action for 30 minutes, the website will sign me out.

How can express I this within the use case model? is it a special requirement for sign in use case?

**2.** I have a use case called "post a job" which done by an employer. The employer can post one job then proceeds to payment, or post more than three jobs and gets 10% discount of the total amount.

Which option should I include in the basic flow and which one should I include in the alternative flow?

**Here is my attempt:**

**Basic flow:**

....

5. System displays an option whether the employer wants to post another job or proceed to payment.
6. The employer selects “proceed to payment” option.
7. System displays total amount and ask the user to press “confirm”.
8. The employer confirms the amount.
9. Make payment use case is performed.
10. System displays a message that job is posted successfully and direct to main employer page.

**Alternate flow:**

Step 5: If user selects “post another job”, steps 3 to 5 are repeated till the employer chooses to pay.

Step 7: If more than 3 jobs are submitted, the system apply 10% discount on the total amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, with the sign-out thing you are modeling something with use cases which use cases are absolutely not meant for.

Use cases are present for giving a high level overview of the business values of a system. What you are trying to do is to model a whole business process inside use cases. That is bound to fail. Your use case "sign out" will not reveal any business value.

For the same reason, [there is no such thing as a "sign in use case"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443682/is-it-necessary-to-include-the-login-for-every-usecase/19445361#19445361).

"post a job offer", in contrast, is a very good use case.

For the details of "post a job offer", consider drawing an activity diagram. That will visualize the flow and thus make it way more intuitive.

The basic flow is always the shortest and most simple flow, where everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

For logoff start with this scenario. You may need to further expand alternate flows or list of validations. No connection to sign in scenario here.

**Scenario 1. System validates user session.**

1. User initiates one of [link to Adornment A: scenarios requiring user authorisation].
2. System validates that

   1. User has a session.
   2. The session is valid for User.
   3. The session has not reached [link to Setting B in Settings section of requirements document: session expiration timeout].
3. System starts execution of the scenario initiated by User.

**Alternate flow: session is not valid.**

Triggered by: validation failed at step 2.

3a. System redirects User to the home page, informs that operation is not permitted, and the use case terminates.

**Adornment A: scenarios requiring user authorisation**

- List of scenarios where users interacts with System and must be authorised.

---

For jobs posting it's better to have a separate subfunction scenario for price calculation. You'd be able to expand it further when marketing will push new price rules and discounts.

**Scenario 2. User posts jobs**

1. User repeats [Link to Scenario 3. User prepares job description] any number of times.
2. User confirms jobs posting.
3. [Link to Scenario 4. System calculates price of posting].
4. User confirms payment.
5. [Link to Scenario 5. User pays for posting].
6. [Link to Scenario 6. System posts jobs].
7. [Link to Scenario 7. System displays users home page].

**Scenario 4. System calculates price of posting**

1. System validates that number of jobs being posted is below [Link to setting D in Settings section: number of simultaneously posted jobs to get a discount].
2. System calculates the price as number of jobs being posted multiplied by [Link to setting E in Settings section: price per posting].

**Alternate flow: mass posting discount**

Triggered by: validation failed at step 1.

2a. System calculates the price as number of jobs being posted multiplied by [Link to setting F in Settings section: discounted price per posting], and the use case terminates.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can set up the case with session timeout as alternative flow like:
   The user waits for 30 minutes
   The website signs user out.
2. You can use main flow as post one job (as it's more common case).
   Also you can add here case, when user does not post any job and left form or clicks on the btn "return".

This will help to test applocation.

But for p. 2 it's better to use decision table to provide all necessary information.

Comment: I put -1 for the reasons explained in my answer (you don't point out the misuse of use case concept).