# Is invalid login a use case or system operation?

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram

`Login` is use case, right? But I am confused about `Invalid login credential`: Is it a use case or a system operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "login" is not a use case. Here is why: [Is it necessary to include the login for every usecase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443682/is-it-necessary-to-include-the-login-for-every-usecase/19445361#19445361)

Login is a common precondition to real use cases.

Second step: Think about the outcomes that bring a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

If a valid login is a use case, then invalid login is a use case. You need to be able to notify your user that a login has failed.

Comment: Changed the answer to reflect your changed question.

Comment: my use case name is "Login to system" , it is not "valid login"

Comment: I'm assuming "login to system" to mean "valid login". What I'm getting at here is that if a successful login is a use case (regardless of what the use case name is), then an unsuccessful login is a use case.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it is an alternative flow in the login use case.

If in your situation this alternate flow turns out to be long and complicated - you can promote it to a separate use case extending login use case.